# How Use QTimer Command

Tags: loops, qt, opencv, video-capture, qtimer

I have a problem in using QTimer command.
I dont have any syntax error, but i have 2 error in qglobal.h and qobjectdefs_impl.h and i dont  understand them.
[image]

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
void MainWindow::updatewindow()
{
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    QImage image((uchar*)frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    QPixmap temp_img = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
    ui->label2->setPixmap(temp_img);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushload_clicked()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, SLOT(updatewindow()));
    timer->start(20);
}
```

I have a problem in using QTimer command.
I dont have any syntax error, but i have 2 error in qglobal.h and qobjectdefs_impl.h and i dont  understand them.

and mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>  
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTimer>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QPixmap Iblackwhite,IMG_Color{};
    QImage image {};
    cv::VideoCapture capture{};
private slots:
      void  updatewindow();

      void on_pushload_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You're mixing Qt4 style with Qt5 style signals. In Qt4 signals where resolved at run-time using the reflection implemented by Qt. In Qt5, signals can be connected type safe and are resolved at compile time (with a compiler error in case). You cannot the styles of Qt4 and Qt5 in one application but not in one `connect()` - this is simply not supported. (Not that you get me wrong: Qt 5 style signals are clearly preferable.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `&MainWindow::updateWindow` instead of `SLOT(updatewindow())`.